# Spring MVC 3.2: returning Document (xml) with @Responsebody

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new with Spring MVC and I have an application that usually returns org.w3c.dom.Document objects (XML Documents). This documents have a lot of different (and dynamic) structures (does not have a specific xsd). I need to know how can I return this objects from my controllers. e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
public Document createFOO(Document myDoc){

 return myDoc;
}
```

When I tried that, I got  HTTP 406 error, and obviously I need a configuration, but I cannot find documentation that solves my problem, because in all of that the solution includes a mapping between a class and a XML, but in my case the object is already a XML Doc. Could you give me a direction to take in my investigation?

Thanks!

Marcos

Edit: This is my configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="my.files"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

---

My example class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("blabla")

public class MyClass{

...

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/xml")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    public Document myMethod(...) {

        Document responseDoc = foo.giveMeaDocument();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your probably missing the `produces` attribute in your `@RequestMapping` annotation. Like this `@RequestMapping(produces = "application/xml")` and of course, like you said, you will need configuration/dependencies in spring to register an appropriate XML converter. Using this you can return a POJO, an not anything specialized like a XML Document.

Comment: Thanks. Which converter should work with this kind of return?

Comment: Yes, something about JAXB2 infrastructure configuration is missing, it is OXM… Who does the conversion type from POJO to XML?

Comment: In the same way ORM requires annotations in the POJO, OXM (JAXB2) has other set too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP/406 error is due to the fact that the document object can't be mapped to the response body.

You will need to make sure you are using <mvc:annotation-driven /> in your XML configuration or the similar construct under JavaConfig style.

**EDIT**

I have implemented a quick and VERY dirty application to demonstrate what I am talking about:

https://github.com/djgraff209/domconversion

See if that meets your needs - be advised it is VERY rough and is only to demonstrate the technology.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: Yes, I have the <context:component-scan... in my application context. In fact, the call is handled correctly, because I debugged it and all is working fine, but the problem appears with the response.

Comment: Component scan is not the same as mvc:annotation-driven. The annotation-driven sets up the handlers to marshall JSON, XML, etc using the @RequestBody/@ResponseBody annotations.

Comment: Oh, Ok. So I didn't knew that. I thought that since I was using @ResponseBody with String successfully (in other controllers), the problem wasn't there. In addition, Do I need a xml converter? If yes: Why? Because the Document object is a XML. Thanks a lot for your replies!

Comment: If you add annotation-driven that should automagically tie that in using the JVM default processing

Comment: I tried that but the problem is not solved yet. My code is like this:
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/xml")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
 @ResponseBody
    public Document createFOO(...) {

        ...
    return aDocument;
}

But the error 406 is still there.

Comment: Interesting - I'll be back with you shortly, need to research this

Comment: I've looked at AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser - this is the spring class responsible for setting up the handler, if you are running on JDK 6+ it should automatically handle this - Can you post your configuration XML or classes?

Comment: Dave, I attached my configuration file in my original post.

Comment: Marcos - I need to do a little more research on this and realize why I fell off a cliff.  The ResponseBody will handle 'JAXB Root Element' annotated classes and marshal them as XML - org.w3c.Document doesn't exactly qualify - be back with answer shortly.

Comment: Hi Dave. Did you find a solution? Maybe we find a issue that has no solution with org.w3c.Document

Comment: One option would be to just register an HTTPMessageConverter to take a DOM document and transform it to the result stream.  It would preserve the 'ResponseBody' annotation and would not necessarily interfere with the default converters - if you require an example let me know I can whip one up.

Comment: I added an example application on Github that demonstrates what I was suggesting in my previous comment.

Comment: Glad to hear it - if you see things that need improvement on GitHub, fork it, make improvement, request pull :-)